# With Android MVVM, how to avoid setting same data in recycler adapter again?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-viewmodel

I need one basic clarification (maybe i’m missing the point). In All MVVM examples, (taking example of postViewModel)

```
    postViewModel.getAllposts().observe(this, new Observer<List<Post>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Post> posts) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG,”posts data set changed, notifying “+posts);
                    postsAdapter.setPosts(posts);
            }
    });
```

And In,

```
    private void getPosts(List<Post> posts) {
            for(Post post:posts) {
                    postViewModel.insert(post);
            }
    }
```

So if there are three posts, for insert of each post, onChanged is called with all posts in DB. 
so first recycler is created with post 1, 
then second time, it’s set with posts 1 and 2 
and at last, it’s set with posts 1,2 and 3. 
So View in recyclerlayout is fine, at the end it shows 3 items only. But it's not efficient if i get lot data which has many images.
How do I avoid this ? Is there a way to pause the observe till all inserts are done ? Or to get only updated data in observe ?

Comment: clear the list, then add

Comment: No, i want to show 3 posts, but not this way where it first loads 1, then 1,2 and then 1,2,3.   With 20 posts in getPosts, it's not efficient.

Comment: why don't you add them all in one go instead inserting one by one.

Comment: Checkout Recyclerview ListAdapter https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter which uses diff utils to handle data changes

Comment: @SohailZahid, i definitely missed that. I can use insertAll in Dao. Thanks, Please add as answer, i'll accept that.

Answer (score 3):

Use [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil) to effectively update your RecyclerView. [Here](https://medium.com/@iammert/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00) is an example